# cakephp 2.x execute controller in javascript

Tags: javascript, php, cakephp

I have the following issue: in cakaphp does not advice anymore the using of jshelper,insted of normal javascript.

```
    <?php
$this->Js->get('#PostCategoryId')->event('change', 
$this->Js->request(array(
'controller'=>'subcategories',
'action'=>'getByCategory'
), array(
'update'=>'#PostSubcategoryId',
'async' => true,
'method' => 'post',
'dataExpression'=>true,
'data'=> $this->Js->serializeForm(array(
'isForm' => true,
'inline' => true
))
))
);
?>
```

I don't know how to execute cake controller in js(without using jshelper):

```
$this->Js->request(array(
'controller'=>'subcategories',
```

Normally in core php, i would do like this:

```
$("select#category").change(function(){
var id = $("select#category option:selected").attr('value');
$.post("select_type.php", {id:id}, function(data){//select_type.php is the "controller"
    $("select#type").html(data);
    });
});
```

But how to use controller in javascript(jquery)?I am not sure but will it works if i do like this:

```
$.post("posts/subcategories/getByCategory", {id:id}, function(data){
```

Comment: Just give it a try it will works. It has nothing to do with cakephp its all jquery. try the console for url browse it on you browser directly, you will know.

Comment: yes it will work just dont forget to add root path in your url, which will be var webroot='<?php echo $this->webroot?>'; and than $.post(webroot+"YOUR CONTROLLER URL",...

Comment: i have a very few experience now with cakephp,lot of things are unclear.
Thats why i need to ask a bit.Thank you so much your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could get the url like this using htmlhelper then it was would be a normal jquery call.

```
var url = <?php
    echo $this->Html->url(array(
    "controller" => "posts",
    "action" => "view"
));

?>;
```

http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/helpers/html.html#HtmlHelper::url